# Kubernetes, http access to app in cluster

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, load-balancing, http, kubernetes

I'm pretty new to the kubernetes. I need some suggestions how to access app which is deployed in cluster.

I have a docker image with Django app and Gunicorn to run .wsgi. I'm using this image to deploy containers in cluster with 3 nodes (environment to learn k8s, 1 master 2 workers). If I expose service with nodePort and use curl <node'sIP>:[port], from server not included to the cluster, I can reach the app.

But now I want to have a single entry point, which would be able to connet with any of replicas.

I thought about creating one more machine, not included to the cluster with installed Nginx or HAproxy, but I can't find any solution how to connect external reverse proxy with kubernetes service.

Can you give me any better solution, or a suggestions how can I move on with my thought?

Comment: Can you tell more about your "environment to learn k8s"? Is this a cluster created locally in VM's (like in Virtualbox) or VM's in the cloud (like GCP or AWS)? You could use `nginx-ingress-controller` with service of type `LoadBalancer` to direct the traffic to your application pods (and have single entrypoint by that).

Comment: I forgot to tell about that, sorry. This cluster is created on Virtualbox VM's. If I'm right, LoadBalancers are available in cloud only, because you have to buy them from provider, tell me if I'm wrong. So this is problem. I searched the internet, and there is only guides for ingress with loadbalancer in cloud. I tried to set up ingress with nodeport service, to have access to app on each node in cluster, but unfortunately I did something wrong, because I still can't reach app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

In the managed Kubernetes clusters like `GKE`, `EKS` or `AKS` you have an ability to request IP addresses for services from your cloud provider.

Kubernetes clusters created for example in `Virtualbox` using either `kubespray`,`kubeadm`  will require additional tools to be able to get the `External-IP` for the services.

You can use `metallb` to assign `External-IP` in clusters not managed by cloud provider. Please take a look on official site:

- *[Metallb.universe.tf](https://metallb.universe.tf/)*

In that case steps to expose an app would be:

- Deploy the app pods
- Create a `service` attached to the pods
- Deploy `metallb` and configure it
- Expose the app by either:

  - Create a service of type `LoadBalancer`
  - Create an `Ingress` resource

> #### Disclaimer!
>
> Creating an `Ingress` resource requires an `Ingress` controller. I've attached below a link to one of it.
>
> - *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)*

I've included an example and more explanation below of how you can expose your app in the cluster created in Virtualbox with `metallb` and `nginx-ingress-controller`.

---

This is an example showing how to expose application on Kubernetes cluster created in Virtualbox with:

- `metallb`
- `nginx-ingress-controller`

I've divided this answer on 2 parts:

- Virtualbox
- Kubernetes

### Virtualbox

When you create your `VM's` in Virtualbox you have multiple ways to configure networking. Some of them are:

- `Bridged networking` - attaching your Kubernetes cluster to physical network
- `Host-only` - allowing single adapter to be connected to nodes and the host allowing network connectivity. This solution requires either another adapter with access to the Internet or a gateway (like for example PfSense) with the same `Host-only` network adapter attached.

This example uses client and 3 nodes with `Bridged` adapters:

- `client` with IP address: `192.168.0.2`
- `master` with IP address: `192.168.0.117`
- `worker1` with IP address: `192.168.0.118`
- `worker2` with IP address: `192.168.0.119`

To make sure this example works outside of the host, I used another device in the same network.

Please make sure the nodes have full connectivity between each other as well as your host have full access to them.

### Kubernetes

Let's assume that:

- Cluster is configured correctly and has access to the Internet
- You have full access to this cluster
- You can "ping" every node from any other host
- Your pod responds to request on port of your choosing (for example `8000`)

Steps:

- Create a pod with `gunicorn`
- Create a service definition for `gunicorn` pod
- Deploy `Metallb`
- Expose app with service of type `LoadBalancer`
- Expose app with `Ingress` resource

#### Create a pod with `gunicorn`

I used below **deployment** definition to create a pod that will respond to requests:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gunicorn
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gunicorn
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gunicorn
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: gunicorn
        image: ubuntu
        command:
        - sleep
        - "infinity"
```

I used `ubuntu` image which I `exec``d into and run below commands:

- `$ apt update && apt install -y python3 python3-pip`
- `$ pip3 install gunicorn`

Example code I used `myapp.py`:

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    data = b"Hello, World!\n"
    start_response("200 OK", [
        ("Content-Type", "text/plain"),
        ("Content-Length", str(len(data)))
    ])
    return iter([data])
```

- `$ gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0 myapp:app &`

Above example is based on:

- *[Gunicorn.org](https://gunicorn.org/)*

After this steps your pod should respond on port `8000` with `Hello, World!`.

#### Create a service definition for `gunicorn` pod

Service definition for `gunicorn` pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gunicorn-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: gunicorn
  ports:
    - name: gunicorn-port
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
  type: NodePort
```

#### Deploy `Metallb`

Following official `Metallb` documentation: *[Metallb.universe.tf: Installation](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/)*:

- Edit `kube-proxy` to change `strictARP` mode from `false` to `true`:

  - `$ kubectl edit configmap -n kube-system kube-proxy`
- `$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.9.3/manifests/namespace.yaml`
- `$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.9.3/manifests/metallb.yaml`
- `$ kubectl create secret generic -n metallb-system memberlist --from-literal=secretkey="$(openssl rand -base64 128)`

You will also need to add a `configMap` that will tell `metallb` which IP addresses he could allocate for services:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.240-192.168.0.250
```

Please take a specific look on part:

```yaml
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.240-192.168.0.250
```

**Please make sure that this address range does not overlap any used addresses in your network and it's in the same network as the nodes and the client.**

After that you should be able to create service of type `LoadBalancer` that will get an IP address.

#### Expose app with service of type `LoadBalancer`

You should be able to run:

- `$ kubectl expose deployment gunicorn --type=LoadBalancer --port=8000`

Output of `$ kubectl get services` should show:

```sh
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
gunicorn           LoadBalancer   10.233.43.104   192.168.0.240   8000:32591/TCP   3s
gunicorn-service   NodePort       10.233.34.96    <none>          8000:30862/TCP   73s
kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.233.0.1      <none>          443/TCP          23h
```

as you can see `gunicorn` service has the `EXTERNAL-IP` of `192.168.0.240` which is in IP pool of `metallb`.

> Physical network used in this example is `192.168.0.0/24`

You can run: `curl 192.168.0.240:8000` and get: `Hello, World!`

#### Expose app with `Ingress` resource

You will need to deploy `Ingress` controller before exposing your app. You can deploy `nginx-ingress-controller` by running:

- `$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`

**This `Ingress` controller will have a service type of `LoadBalancer` attached to it and this will be the **entrypoint** for the request.**

You can get it's IP address by invoking: `$ kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx`:

```sh
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.233.52.8     192.168.0.241   80:31380/TCP,443:30066/TCP   29m
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.233.37.255   <none>          443/TCP                      29m
```

Here is the `Ingress` definition to route the traffic from controller to your pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gunicorn-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: gunicorn-service
          servicePort: gunicorn-port
```

After applying it, you should be able to:

- `curl 192.168.0.241` and get the response from `gunicorn`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is best guide on SE I've ever seen. To be honest, Metallb was a missing part in my infrastructure. I didn't know this type of software exist. I appreciate your hard work, but I stuck after exposing loadbalancer service. I changed strictARP to true, applied namespace, created controller and speakers, generated secret. Also I applied configMap with correct IP range .2.240-.2.250 (192.168.2.0/24 network). I exposed deployment with loadbalancer, but all time status of External-IP is pending :(

Comment: I forgot to add this but please check if you have the `kube-proxy` in iptables or ipvs mode. If you have it in iptables please do not change the strict mode on arp.

Comment: Also, please check the logs of the controller and the speaker.

Comment: I looked to the logs and controller is not able to reach kubernetes Cluster-IP service (10.96.0.1) on port 443 `reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/metallb-system/configmaps?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dconfig&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host` also it shows failed to list *v1.Service. Speakers had some problem with `memberlist: Failed to join <ip> : dial tcp 192.168.2.3:7946: connect: no route to host`

Comment: How did you configure/deploy your cluster? What CNI plugin are you using?

Comment: I used kubeadm with --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.2.1. I'm using latest flannel CNI

Comment: Please check your `CoreDNS` pod. If it's having an IP address, if it produces any logs(errors) and if it's restarting.

Comment: I have two coredns pods. First produced 2 errors `[ERROR] plugin/errors: HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.28:43017->8.8.8.8:53: read: no route to host
[ERROR] plugin/errors:  read udp 10.244.0.28:59154->8.8.8.8:53: read: no route to host
`and second produced 3 of the same kind. Pods still runinng without restart. Both have IP '10.244.0.27-28'. Some time ago they throw warning to `describe pods` `Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "coredns-id" network: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory' but latest log is 'Started container coredns`

Comment: What is your master IP address and your gateway address? What is the operating system you are using on those machines (master and nodes)?  Please try to create 2 pods on seperate nodes and try to connect from pod on node1 to the pod on node2 (`$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx`, `$ kubectl scale deployment nginx --replicas=10`, exec into pod, `curl ANOTHER_POD_IP`).

Comment: Today I had sometime to play with this again. I didn't debug this system, but I created new environment  with 1 master, 2 workers, 1 docker repo out of cluster. I set up everything as in case above (I wrote to notepad step by step what I enter to terminal so everything is the same), with one diffrence. I just firstly added workers to cluster and then installed CNI. In case, we discussed, first I deployed CNI and then added machines. And this is strange because, in new environment my loadbalancer got 192.168.2.240, and I can reach app with ths. Would It matter what action I performed first?

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a couple of fundamental Kubernetes concepts that I recommend you look at:

1. [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) - these provide an abstraction over your pods and provide a way to load balance traffic over multiple replicas. These can be used internally, or exposed externally
2. [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) - this allows you to setup an Ingress controller inside your cluster, like Nginx, and have this reverse proxy your traffic to the appropriate services. This is a much better approach than creating an Nginx instance outside your cluster, as an Ingress controller will automatically pickup any new ingresses you create in your cluster.